# How to find how many entries are within a specific time period

Tags: excel

I have this data (as been below), I was wondering how I can figure out how many entries are between `00:00:00-00:59:59`, then in `01:00:00-1:59:59` etc. So the date isn't really considered, its just the time.

```
id  |  date
1   |  2018-11-08 01:40:49
2   |  2018-11-08 04:08:12
3   |  2018-11-25 15:19:44
4   |  2018-12-14 01:34:01
```

**CSV Version:**

```
id,date
1,2018-11-08 01:40:49
2,2018-11-08 04:08:12
3,2018-11-25 15:19:44
4,2018-12-14 01:34:01
```

---

So my expected data would be like:

```
Start Period  |  End Period  |  amount
00:00:00      |  00:59:59    |  0
01:00:00      |  01:59:59    |  2
02:00:00      |  02:59:59    |  0
03:00:00      |  03:59:59    |  0
04:00:00      |  04:59:59    |  1
05:00:00      |  05:59:59    |  0
...
And so on
```

**CSV Version:**

```
Start Period,End Period,amount
00:00:00,00:59:59,something here
00:01:00,01:59:59,something here
00:02:00,02:59:59,something here
00:03:00,03:59:59,something here
00:04:00,04:59:59,something here
00:05:00,05:59:59,something here
00:06:00,06:59:59,something here
00:07:00,07:59:59,something here
00:08:00,08:59:59,something here
00:09:00,09:59:59,something here
00:10:00,10:59:59,something here
00:11:00,11:59:59,something here
00:12:00,12:59:59,something here
00:13:00,13:59:59,something here
00:14:00,14:59:59,something here
00:15:00,15:59:59,something here
00:16:00,16:59:59,something here
00:17:00,17:59:59,something here
00:18:00,18:59:59,something here
00:19:00,19:59:59,something here
00:20:00,20:59:59,something here
00:21:00,21:59:59,something here
00:22:00,22:59:59,something here
00:23:00,23:59:59,something here
```

Comment: Is your time period one or two columns?

Comment: I have never done this, but you should probably take the calendar table approach.  Create two columns, one for start, one for end.  Then join that table to your data set.

Comment: @VBAPete 1 column. The expect data can be a start and end time. The expected format can be whatever format. Though the actual data itself, I cannot change

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try the following `sumproduct` function with embedded `hour` functions:

> =SUMPRODUCT(--(HOUR(**date range**)>=**start period** *24),--(HOUR(**date range**) < **end period** *24))

[image]

Make sure that you only select the date range and not the entire column.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't completely work. For example if the date is `2015-11-25 7:01:24` it doesn't work

Comment: Did you check that your date range is set correctly? Seems to be working for me (see updated picture above)

Comment: Here is a screenshot https://i.imgur.com/q7HUkf5.png It doesn't count 4pm now. https://i.imgur.com/e2rP0c6.png

Comment: Can you also post a screenshot of the content of cell B3?

Comment: Excel auto formatted it before. I've changed it back so it looks like it does in the csv. https://i.imgur.com/JJcC259.png https://i.imgur.com/lhssyJI.png

Comment: I'm struggling to replicate the error, because all of your date stamps works for me. But your formula is definitely correct.

Comment: I figured it out. Its because my start and end times were automatically formatted my excel. So I re-typed them in the text format and it started working. Also I just have 1l last question. The place where you wrote date range, is there a way to select the date range automatically. I know the date range starts at B2, but my actual excel sheet auto updates and the rows keep increment. Is there a way to select rows that only contain data?

Comment: You won't be able to just do that using a formula, but you could program that in VBA pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

If *Date* is in column B then put this under *amount* and fill down.,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(HOUR(B$2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)))=(ROW(1:1)-1)))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcQDx.png)

Comment: I am honestly lost with this. I edited my first post to be more clear. Could you explain this again?

Comment: so where does it say in this formula, the actual hour it is checking?

Comment: Put `=row(1:1)-1` into a cell at the top of an unused column and fill down.

Comment: i there a way to change this formula so I can put in a specific start period and end period, like in the my edited first post?